# Unable to evaluate functions in Go debugging using delve

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, dead-code, delve, dlv

I'm on an M1 Mac (ARM64 chip) and still unable to invoke functions via the debugger in VSCode which is using the DLV backend.

### Debug Console

```
call test()
Unable to evaluate expression: could not find symbol value for test

test()
Unable to evaluate expression: function calls not allowed without using 'call'
```

I'm using the latest DLV:

```
~ ❯ dlv version                                                                                                                                                     
Delve Debugger
Version: 1.20.1
Build: $Id: 96e65b6c615845d42e0e31d903f6475b0e4ece6e
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Which command did you use to compile your program? Maybe you [accidentally stripped some symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66405077)?

Comment: Hm, I'm just hitting the debug button. Do you have recommendations for some setup?

Answer (score 0):

If your `test` function is in a `*_test.go` file, it may not actually exist unless one of your `Test*` functions calls it -- I found this to be true for my code.

It seems like `go` may be stripping  out functions that aren't called by test code.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to **dead code elimination**. Next is the doc copied from [cmd/link/internal/ld/deadcode.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/cecf8b93283dd9fddacdf05db583644a2f3b0bbb/src/cmd/link/internal/ld/deadcode.go#L351-L385):

> The basis of the dead code elimination is a flood fill of symbols,
> following their relocations, beginning at `*flagEntrySymbol`.
>
> This flood fill is wrapped in logic for pruning unused methods.
> All methods are mentioned by relocations on their receiver's `*rtype`.
> These relocations are specially defined as `R_METHODOFF` by the compiler
> so we can detect and manipulated them here.
>
> There are three ways a method of a reachable type can be invoked:
>
> 1. direct call
> 2. through a reachable interface type
> 3. reflect.Value.Method (or MethodByName), or reflect.Type.Method
>    (or MethodByName)
>
> The first case is handled by the flood fill, a directly called method
> is marked as reachable.
>
> The second case is handled by decomposing all reachable interface
> types into method signatures. Each encountered method is compared
> against the interface method signatures, if it matches it is marked
> as reachable. This is extremely conservative, but easy and correct.
>
> The third case is handled by looking to see if any of:
>
> - `reflect.Value.Method` or `MethodByName` is reachable
> - `reflect.Type.Method` or `MethodByName` is called (through the
>   `REFLECTMETHOD` attribute marked by the compiler).
>
> If any of these happen, all bets are off and all exported methods
> of reachable types are marked reachable.
>
> **Any unreached text symbols are removed from `ctxt.Textp`**.

For example, the `test` func below is dead code and will be eliminated.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world!")
}

func test() string {
    return "test"
}
```

We can verify the elimination with `go tool nm`:

```
$ go build -gcflags="all=-N -l" -o main main.go
$ go tool nm main | grep -F " main."
  524000 D main..inittask
  49cbc0 T main.main
```

And `call test()` failed in this case.

Now let's add `var _ = test()`:

```
+ var _ = test()
  func test() string {
    return "test"
  }
```

And try again:

```
$ go build -gcflags="all=-N -l" -o main main.go
go tool nm main | grep -F " main."
  524720 D main..inittask
  49cc80 T main.init
  49cbc0 T main.main
  49cc40 T main.test
```

We have the symbol `main.test` this time. And `call test()` works:

```
$ dlv debug main.go                                                                                                                                        36s 00:36:33
Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) c main.main
Breakpoint 1 set at 0x49cbc6 for main.main() ./main.go:7
> main.main() ./main.go:7 (hits goroutine(1):1 total:1) (PC: 0x49cbc6)
     2: 
     3: import (
     4:     "fmt"
     5: )
     6: 
=>   7: func main() {
     8:     fmt.Println("Hello world!")
     9: }
    10: 
    11: var _ = test()
    12: func test() string {
(dlv) n
> main.main() ./main.go:8 (PC: 0x49cbd4)
     3: import (
     4:     "fmt"
     5: )
     6: 
     7: func main() {
=>   8:     fmt.Println("Hello world!")
     9: }
    10: 
    11: var _ = test()
    12: func test() string {
    13:     return "test"
(dlv) call test()
> main.main() ./main.go:8 (PC: 0x49cbd4)
Values returned:
    ~r0: "test"
```